# Get 'utm_' campaign parameters in controller

Tags: magento2, parameter

I am trying to get the campaign values from the URL parameters, for tracking in Magento, inside a controller action.

I am using `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface->getParam('utm_source')` and it returns empty value, or getParams() and checking the param array, 'utm_source' is missing.

This happens if the URL is like this:
`https://example.com/frontName/controllerName/actionName/?utm_source=test`

If the URL is:
`https://example.com/frontName/controllerName/actionName/utm_source/test`

or like this:
`https://example.com/frontName/controllerName/actionName/?utm%5Fsource=test`

then 'utm_source' is present in the params array.

I am trying `Magento\Framework\UrlInterface->getCurrentUrl()` and the `utm_` query params are missing from the url. If I have multiple params, both `utm_` and non `utm_` like this:

`https://example.com/frontName/controllerName/actionName/?utm_source=test&test=value&utm_campaign=testcampaign`
then getCurrentUrl() returns `https://example.com/frontName/controllerName/actionName/?test=value`

I have searched for `utm_` everywhere inside the vendor folder, the only place I have found is in `module-page-cache/etc/varnish4/5/6.vcl`, which is excluding `utm_` from caching.

So, how does one get the param?

Comment: I have also faced this issue. Do not remember the exact solution but I use one of these. First solution is try to get it using $_GET and second solution is parse the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since somebody else might have the same issue.

I have opened a support ticket with Adobe, this is the response that I've got:
[image]

Followed the instructions and now everything is working as expected.

But, basically, you can exclude some parameters from a link, so that you can cache that page. Because, a lot of times, you have google or other platforms adding unique parameters to your URL, so that the campaign can be tracked. But, the page is the same, even if the params are the different. So for example you can have example.com/?utm_source=facebook and example.com/?utm_source=google. To avoid caching each page separately, you can ignore this utm_source param at all.

Answer (score 0):

Requirement = From URL such as `http://base-url/test/index/utm?utm_source=154&utm_medium=medium&utm_content=casonsad`

You want to get utm_source, `utm_medium`, and `utm_content` values using the Magento controller.

Solution is

```
namespace Abbas\Test\Controller\Index;

class Utm extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        var_dump($_GET);
    }
}
namespace Abbas\Test\Controller\Index;

class Utm extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        var_dump($_GET);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do not use $_GET or $_POST, instead use the requestInterface.
Do not extend the action class, instead, implement the post or get interface

Answer (score 0):

If your controller extended `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` then using

using `$this->getRequest()->getParams();` you get all **Get and Post** params values.

For getting for a single get param use `$this->getRequest()->getParam({paramName});`. Example: `$this->getRequest()->getParam('utm_medium')`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same on my PC, which has nothin to do with work environment, and it works fine, I do get the parameter. When trying it in our work adobe commerce cloud environment, or even a clean Magento instance on my work machine, then the issue is present, so, I guess it has something to do with our network or something else. Will raise this with our management. Thanks

Comment: Hey did you get a solution for your problem. I am also facing the same issue, can you guide me?

Comment: Check marked accepted response, I have added it in there